# <span> Text updates based on <select> option

Tags: angularjs

I've the following `<select>` element:

```
<select ng-model="pTitle">
  <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
  <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
  <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
</select>
```

When an option is selected, I'm changing text like so.

```
<section>
    Greetings, <span ng-bind="pTitle"></span> Jones!
</section>
```

This works great. Now what I'd like to do is change other text based on the `ng-bind` change.

For example, in the `<section>` below, based on their choice I'd switch between `his` and `her`:

```
<section>
    According to <span ng-bind="pTitle"></span> Jones, his **(or her)** coding ability needs some work!
</section>
```

What's the proper way to get this done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <select ng-model="pTitle">
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  </select>

  <section>
    According to <span ng-bind="pTitle"></span> Jones,  <span ng-if="pTitle=='Mr.'">His</span><span ng-if="pTitle=='Mrs.'||pTitle=='Ms.'">Her</span> coding ability needs some work!
  </section>
</div>
```

**Update**: Angular 1.1.5 added a ternary operator, so now we can simply write

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <select ng-model="pTitle">
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  </select>

  <section>
    According to <span ng-bind="pTitle"></span> Jones, {{ pTitle == 'Mr.' ? 'His' : 'Her' }} coding ability needs some work!
  </section>
</div>
```

or in previous versions

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <select ng-model="pTitle">
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  </select>

  <section>
    According to <span ng-bind="pTitle"></span> Jones, {{ pTitle == 'Mr.' && 'His' || 'Her' }} coding ability needs some work!
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Although these answers actually work, they're bad practices since you would have a lot of duplicated code. Even worst if you need to add another option

Comment: @gfpacheco : It will be worst , when he repeating this. In that case it will be better to use filter as per your answer...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) that transforms the selected value to the wanted pronoum.

Like:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('possessivePronoum', function() {
  return function(title) {
    return title === 'Mr.' ? 'his' : 'her';
  };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<section>
  According to <span ng-bind="pTitle"></span> Jones, <span ng-bind="pTitle | possessivePronoum"></span> coding ability needs some work!
</section>
```

**Warning: untested code**